# Is there a way to access a model field from its corresponding model form field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Models.py:

```
class ItemImage(Model):
    image = ImageField(upload_to=get_user_upload_path)
```

Forms.py:

```
class ItemImageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ItemImage
```

Say, I initialized an `ItemImageForm` with an instance of `ItemImage` and added the form as `img_form` to the context used for rendering the template with. I know that I can access the corresponding `ItemImage` instance with `img_form.instance`. But I am curious if there's a more direct way to access `ItemImage.image` from its corresponding `img_form.image`?

Comment: why would you want to do that? In the view you already have the instance, so pass that object as another value in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't be accessed at all. The form consists of initial data and cleaned data. If you refer to initial data, use `instance`. If you need value after user's action, call `is_valid` or `full_clean` and later look for value in `cleaned_data`. Everything in between is hacking.

If you want to perform any special cleaning on `img_form.image`, create `clean_image` method, but you're probably aware of that already.

Comment: Yes, but it's always better to have confirmation on what I think I know. Thanks.